# Problem extracting scan results with Metasploit using Python

Tags: python, export-to-csv

## I'm trying to extract the scan results for each ip address from RHOSTS, but the problem is that the scan results are displayed for some ip addresses and others not , here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import csv
import re
# Define global variables
console_id = 0
outfile = None
console = None
msf_client = None
def parse_msf_scan_output(input_file, output_file):
    # Ouvrir le fichier contenant les résultats des scans
    with open(input_file, "r") as file:
        # Lire le contenu du fichier ligne par ligne
        lines = file.readlines()

    # Ouvrir le fichier de sortie
    with open(output_file, "w") as outfile:
        # Écrire l'en-tête du fichier
        outfile.write("ip_address,scan_name,result\n")

        # Variables pour stocker les informations actuelles
        scan_name = None
        ip_addresses = []

        # Parcourir chaque ligne du fichier
        for line in lines:
            # Si la ligne commence par "Scan name:", enregistrer le nom du scan
            if line.startswith("Scan name:"):
                scan_name = line.split(":")[1].strip()
                ip_addresses = []  # Réinitialiser la liste des adresses IP

            # Si la ligne contient "RHOSTS =>", extraire les adresses IP
            elif "RHOSTS =>" in line:
                ips = line.split("RHOSTS =>")[1].split()
                ip_addresses.extend(ips)

                print(ip_addresses)
                print(scan_name)

            # Si la ligne commence par "[*]" ou "[-]", écrire dans le fichier de sortie
            elif line.startswith("[*]") or line.startswith("[-]"):
                status, content = line.split(" ", 1)
                result = content.strip()

                # Parcourir chaque adresse IP
                for ip_address in ip_addresses:
                    # Condition 1: Si result contient une adresse IP
                    if ip_address in result:
                        # Écrire dans le fichier de sortie
                        outfile.write(f"{ip_address},{scan_name},{result}\n")
                        break  # Sortir de la boucle interne après avoir écrit une ligne
                    # Condition 2: Si result ne contient pas d'adresse IP
                    elif not any(ip in result for ip in ips):
                        # Écrire dans le fichier de sortie avec la première adresse IP de la liste
                        outfile.write(f"{ip_addresses[0]},{scan_name},{result}\n")
                        break  # Sortir de la boucle interne après avoir écrit une ligne

def main():

    parse_msf_scan_output("msf_scan_output.txt", "msf_scan_results.csv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## here is an extract from the file msf_scan_output.txt"

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scan name: auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_neighbor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[*] Workspace 'msf_scanner' already existed, switching to it.
[*] Workspace: msf_scanner
[!] Unknown datastore option: THREADS.
THREADS => 10
[*] Workspace: msf_scanner
RHOSTS => 192.168.56.103 192.168.56.101
[-] Auxiliary failed: RuntimeError eth0: You don't have permission to perform this capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)
[-] Call stack:
[-]   /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/exploit/capture.rb:124:in `open_live'
[-]   /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/exploit/capture.rb:124:in `open_pcap'
[-]   /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_neighbor.rb:40:in `run_batch'
[-]   /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/auxiliary/scanner.rb:213:in `block in run'
[-]   /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/thread_manager.rb:105:in `block in spawn'
[*] Auxiliary module execution completed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scan name: auxiliary/scanner/smb/smb_login
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[*] Workspace 'msf_scanner' already existed, switching to it.
[*] Workspace: msf_scanner
THREADS => 10
[*] Workspace: msf_scanner
SMBDomain => WORKGROUP
BLANK_PASSWORDS => true
USER_AS_PASS => true
SMBUser => Administrator
PASS_FILE => /usr/share/wordlists/crest_allwords.txt
RHOSTS => 192.168.56.103 192.168.56.101
[-] Msf::OptionValidateError The following options failed to validate:
[-] Invalid option PASS_FILE: for rhosts value 192.168.56.103, for rhosts value 192.168.56.101
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## here is an extract from the file "msf_scan_results.csv"

## here the scan auxiliary/scanner/smb/smb_login for example the result is only displayed for 192.168.56.103

```
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/x11/open_x11,192.168.56.103:6000   - 192.168.56.103 Access Denied
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/x11/open_x11,Scanned 1 of 2 hosts (50% complete)
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/x11/open_x11,Scanned 1 of 2 hosts (50% complete)
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/x11/open_x11,Scanned 1 of 2 hosts (50% complete)
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/x11/open_x11,Scanned 2 of 2 hosts (100% complete)
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/x11/open_x11,Auxiliary module execution completed
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,Running module against 192.168.56.103
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,Auxiliary failed: RuntimeError eth0: You don't have permission to perform this capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,Call stack:
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/exploit/capture.rb:124:in `open_live'
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/exploit/capture.rb:124:in `open_pcap'
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping.rb:63:in `run'
192.168.56.101,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,Running module against 192.168.56.101
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,Auxiliary failed: RuntimeError eth0: You don't have permission to perform this capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,Call stack:
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/exploit/capture.rb:124:in `open_live'
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/exploit/capture.rb:124:in `open_pcap'
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping.rb:63:in `run'
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_multicast_ping,Auxiliary module execution completed
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_neighbor,Auxiliary failed: RuntimeError eth0: You don't have permission to perform this capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_neighbor,Call stack:
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_neighbor,/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/exploit/capture.rb:124:in `open_live'
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_neighbor,/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/exploit/capture.rb:124:in `open_pcap'
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_neighbor,/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_neighbor.rb:40:in `run_batch'
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_neighbor,/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/auxiliary/scanner.rb:213:in `block in run'
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_neighbor,/usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msf/core/thread_manager.rb:105:in `block in spawn'
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/discovery/ipv6_neighbor,Auxiliary module execution completed
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/smb/smb_login,Msf::OptionValidateError The following options failed to validate:
192.168.56.103,auxiliary/scanner/smb/smb_login,Invalid option PASS_FILE: for rhosts value 192.168.56.103, for rhosts value 192.168.56.101
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with metasploit? This problem is unrelated to metasploit. You aren't even using the imported `MsfRpcClient`.

Comment: And you aren't getting all IPs, because you are breaking out off the loop on the first IP found.